# Nginx redirects map to other urls

Tags: nginx, redirect

I wanted to have it so for example if you go to `example.com/some-page` it would take you to `example.com/other-page` (some of these may go off-site too). I have about a hundred of these so it would be better if I could have them in a map.

Currently I have this in my `sites-enabled` file:
`map $request_uri $new_uri { include /var/www/example.com/redirects.map; }`
Not sure really what to do since im new to nginx but all help appreciated